# Extending the TextInput class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textinput

Extend the TextInput Class/component to accept a "value" property as a number. I know there is a restrict method, that only allows for specified characters. The problem I am having is using a textinput to take the value in the box and apply it to math equations in a script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the `TextInput` to `0-9.` and then use its value in the script by casting it to a Number.

```
Math.sqrt(Number(textInput.text));
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Amarghosh's:

You'll need to restrict something like this: "0-9\-" if you allow negatives. (yes triple-escaped...)

Also, there's the parseInt and parseFloat methods if you need specialized options like parsing from Hex.

Just make sure you check your result for NaN: `isNan(result)?`.